# Working with WindowsBuilder Pro

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, ubuntu, miglayout

I'm trying out WindowsBuilder Pro to develop Swing UI. I'm using MiGLayout Manager. While developing in Design View, When I create a new Item ( JLabel, JTextField etc), the box to edit appears away from the actual component which can be seen in the picture.

[image: Error Rendering in WindowsBuilder Pro]

I've searched about WindowsBuilder Pro and MiGLayout but found working correctly as can be seen in figure from [this link](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/miglayout#MainFeatures)

[image: Fine working WindowsBuilder Pro]

I'm using Eclipse in my Ubuntu 12.10 x64 system.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Which Eclipse/WindowBuilder Pro version are you using?

Comment: I'm using WindowsBuilder Pro 1.5.1 using Juno Update Site.

Comment: There is no official version of [WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro) for Juno.Could be this the problem but I'm not 100% sure. Which Java version have you installed and using on your machine?

Comment: I'm using update site for WindowBuilder Pro from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php). About version of java, `java -version` command on my machine gave following output.`java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
`

Answer (score -1):

Or rehaces the layout or view the code manually. Must be that adding and deleting components has been garbage.